# Is there a way to further filter down search results in a workspace search in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, search, filter

On a bigger project, there are times a keyword is appearing in hundreds of files - is there a way to further filter the results down?

Answer (score 0):

Type text into the filter bar to restrict the items displayed in the content area of the navigator. Click the icons in the filter bar to display only recently changed files or only files with source control status. You can also add a file to the project by clicking the Add (+) button.

From : [`https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/DevelopYourAppintheWorkspaceWindow/DevelopYourAppintheWorkspaceWindow.html`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/DevelopYourAppintheWorkspaceWindow/DevelopYourAppintheWorkspaceWindow.html)

Hope it helps